# Excel VBA macro to delete rows if certain row is greater than 0 for extremely large worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, delete-row

I'm still very new to creating macros, and I'm having trouble finding a macro that can delete entire rows of data for a spreadsheet that can vary in size, but typically be about 100k rows.

The condition is if a cell (in this case anything in row 'AN') is greater than 0, then delete the entire row.

I'm currently trying to use something like below, but Excel does not seem to like the code due to the size of the spreadsheet, since it will never finish.

```
    last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = last To 2 Step -1
                If (Cells(i, "AN").Value) > 0 Then
                Cells(i, "AN").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i
```

Is there a different way to write the code so it doesn't put so much strain on trying to process through 100k rows of data?

Thanks!

Comment: Use Filter and delete visable.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to save computing power. It turns off certain functions that are unnecessary while the macro runs, then turns them back on. There's more complicated ways that check the settings and saves them and reverts them afterwards, but these are usually the basics.

```
Private Sub TurnOffFunctions()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False

End Sub

Private Sub TurnOnFunctions()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayStatusBar = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub

Sub DeleteRows()

Call TurnOnFunctions

    last = Cells(Rows.Count, "AN").End(xlUp).Row
            For i = last To 2 Step -1
                If (Cells(i, "AN").Value) > 0 Then
                Cells(i, "AN").EntireRow.Delete
        End If
    Next i

Call TurnOffFunctions

End Sub
```